# Keep the first 2 parts of the string having a separator

Tags: regex, string, perl

Is there a more succinct/perlish way for the following:

```
my @components = split /-/, $original;
my $final_string = $components[0]."-".$components[1];
```

Input is a string with at most 2 `-` and the last is optional. I always want to keep the first part. I.e. `10-9-1` should become `10-9` and `10-9` as input should remain `10-9`

Comment: `$original=~s/^([^\-]+\-\d+)(.+)$/$1/g;`

Comment: @ssr1012: That modifies the `$original`?

Comment: `($mynew = $original)=~s/^([^\-]+\-\d+)(.+)$/$1/g; print $mynew;`

Comment: This will not modify the original values

Answer (score 5):

```
use Modern::Perl;

my $re = qr/-\d+\K.*$/;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s/$re//;
    say;
}
__DATA__
10-9-1
10-9
```

For just a string:

```
my $original = '10-9-1';
(my $final = $original) =~ s/-\d+\K.*$//;
say $final;
```

**Explantion:**

```
s/
    -       # find the first dash in the string
    \d+     # 1 or more digits
    \K      # forget all we have seen until this posiiton
    .*      # rest of the line
    $       # end of line
//
```

Comment: How does that capture the last part only?

Comment: What's the point in declaring an extra `$re` variable outside of the loop?

Comment: Your code doesn't work for `"3-4-5\n"`. It produces `"3-4\n"` instead of `"3-4"`.

Comment: @melpomene: That's just a habit of mine.

Comment: @melpomene: That wasn't said in OP. But to fixed replace `$` with `\R?`

Comment: @Toto Then it will turn `"3-4-\r\n56"` into `"3-456"`.

Comment: @melpomene: Then, use `/s` flag.

Answer (score 4):

It's easier to use a regex match here.

```
my ($final_string) = $original =~ /^([^-]*-[^-]*)/;
```

If you want to do the change in place, a substitution works great.

```
$original =~ s/^[^-]*-[^-]*\K.*//s;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$original =~ m/^([^\-]+\-[^\-]+)/ or warn "Unable to match regex in string: $original";
my $final_string = $1;
```

Think this will answer your query. Its not limited by any particular string - like the text after the hyphen should be a digit or anything. It'll warn you if its not matched too.
This is assuming the `$original` variable has only one instance to be matched (inferred from the code in the question).

Comment: Does this modify `$original`?

Comment: Nope. It'll update `$final_string` string with the matched regex string and will leave the original intact

Comment: Note: that will put whatever happened to be in `$1` previously into `$final_string` if the pattern doesn't match.

Answer (score 2):

The regex solutions you've got are probably the best approach, but it's also possible to do it with `split()` and `join()`.

```
# You need this to use 'say()'
use feature 'say';

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;

  say join '-', (split /-/)[0, 1];
}

__DATA__
10-9-1
10-9
```

The `(split /-/)[0, 1]` takes the list returned from `split()` and gives you the first two elements of the list.

Comment: I can get this code working ... but not Dave Cross'. Any ideas?
while (<FIN>){
chomp;
@_ = split(/-/);
say join '-', $_[0], $_[1];
}

Comment: @MichaelG.: That seems to be a more complex version of my code. Not sure why you've split it into two statements. Seems unnecessary to me. Also, please don't use `@_` for anything other than its actual meaning (subroutine parameters).

Comment: @MichaelG.: *I can get this code working* - You'll need to give us more information. What unexpected behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: I'm in no position to disagree. I couldn't get this to compile (split /-/)[0, 1]. I will post my unauthorised version below.

Comment: I've added the `use feature` line which should solve any compilation problems.